# Swift: deallocate modally presented view controller

Tags: swift, memory-management, uisearchcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, dealloc

I have a modally presented SearchviewController that contains a UISearchController.
When swiping down it gets deallocated, but only if the searchControllers searchBar is not in editing mode. Only if I press its cancel button in advance, it gets deallocated.
How can I make sure it gets deallocated, even when in editing mode? There are definitely no strong self references within any closures...

Presenting ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    addButton()
}

func addButton() {
    let mediumConfiguration = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(scale: .large)
    var checkButtonImage = UIImage(systemName: "plus", withConfiguration: mediumConfiguration)
    checkButtonImage = checkButtonImage?.withTintColor(.label)
    
    let button = UIButton(type: .contactAdd)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onAddViewControllerButtonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    
    view.addSubview(button)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
}
@objc func onAddViewControllerButtonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    
    let viewController = SearchViewController()
    viewController.view.backgroundColor = .secondarySystemBackground
    
    let navigationController = UINavigationController()
    navigationController.viewControllers = [viewController]
    
    self.present(navigationController, animated: true)
}
```

}

Presented ViewController:

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureSearchController()
}

var searchController: UISearchController?
func configureSearchController() {
    //search
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController?.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController?.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
    searchController?.searchBar.keyboardType = .webSearch
    self.navigationItem.searchController?.searchBar.backgroundColor = .clear
    self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
    self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
}
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    return
}

//check deallocation
deinit { print("\(NSStringFromClass(type(of: self))): deallocated") }
```

}

Can you help with that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Added a sample code. Again: when swiping down to dismiss the presented view controller, it does not get deallocated when search bar is in editing mode. End editing does not help, only if I click the cancel button before swiping down, my dismiss func gets called...

Comment: Can you explain why you are saying `showDetailViewController`? Outside of a split view controller that's a very weird thing to say.

Comment: Edited again (was copied and pasted from my project). Now I'm calling self.present... But this obviously makes no difference regarding deallocation.

Comment: One more question: you say "my dismiss func gets called". What is your "dismiss" func? Are you trying somewhere to detect dismissal of the presented view controller? Because deinit is not how to do that.

Comment: sorry I meant "deinit". But anyway, I just added "deinit { print("\(NSStringFromClass(type(of: self))): deallocated") } to check if it gets deallocated (which it does not, when the search bars cancel button was not clicked before).
And yes, I'm a rookie ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding

```swift
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    self.navigationItem.searchController = nil
}
```

to `SearchViewController` fixes the problem for me, but admittedly I have no idea as to *why* this is necessary.